# Difference between numpy.rint and numpy.round

Tags: python, numpy

What is the difference between numpy.rint and numpy.round/numpy.around?  They both seem to perform the same function:

```
>>> a
array([-1.7, -1.5, -0.2,  0.2,  1.5,  1.7,  2. ])
>>> np.round(a)
array([-2., -2., -0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.])
>>> np.rint(a)
array([-2., -2., -0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.])
```

Comment: round is rounding to the decimal point and rint is always rounding to the nearest integer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the difference:

```
A = np.array([-1.72, -1.58, -0.2, 0.2, 1.5, 1.7, 2.0])
np.round(A,1)
array([-1.7, -1.6, -0.2,  0.2,  1.5,  1.7,  2. ])
np.rint(A)
array([-2., -2., -0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.])
```

You basically use `np.round()` when you want to round to any decimal place, like here I have done it for one decimal, so I got `-1.7` for `-1.72` instead of `-2` which I got in `np.rint()`

One possible reason for having `np.rint(x)` when `np.round(x,0)` can get our job done is the speed of computation which the former offers us. When I ran both the snippets of code and recorded the timing for the operation this is what I got

```
%%timeit
np.round(A,0)
5.16 µs ± 495 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each) 

%%timeit
np.rint(A)
1.06 µs ± 28.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

We can very well see that `np.rint()` gets the job done approximately five times faster than `np.round()`.

Comment: Then why should one use np.rint if there is np.round?

Comment: One possible that I could think for this is the speed of computation, I have updated my answer kindly have a look at it.

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference between them for larger arrays: Using numpy 1.19.2, for `A = np.random.rand(10000, 1000)`, I get `np.round(A)` to be 20.4ms, and `np.rint(A)` to be 20 ms.